# Function available in whole project C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# project with many winforms in it. I would like to have a function available to all of these forms. The solution I have right now is a separate class with this function, and then in the forms like this:

```cs
Exit quitter = new Exit();
            quitter.exitProgram(sender, e);
```

Is there a better way for my fnction to be available inside every form without having to initialize a class with this function every time?

Comment: Write a static method instead of an instance method?

Comment: Base Class for the forms?

Comment: If I knew what was the difference between these, I would not have to ask about it. Can you give me some explanation and example of a static method? Do I just put a function with the keyword static in the program.cs file in my project and it will be available in each form?

Comment: @TymekWojnarowski yes that'll work. For examples you can serach the internet, there are plenty. You could also use an extension method depending on your use case.

Comment: @Postlagerkarte If now my forms are inheriting from the class Form, then I can make a class "FormBase" which inherits from the class Form and then make my forms inherit from FormBase?

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with static vs instance members, I'd *strongly* recommend that you get hold of a good beginner's C# book and read the appropriate section. GUI programming is tricky enough even when you know the language well - it's likely to be very, very hard if you're not familiar with the basics.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am learning from "Head First C#" book by Greene and Stellman

Comment: Right - in the copy I've got, `static` is covered early in chapter 3. Things may have moved around for later editions, but I'd still hope it's covered fairly early. It's a really, really important concept to understand.

Comment: @JonSkeet then I shall give this a lot of my attention, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a `helper` class, which will contain all common functionalities shared by all winforms and write static method to avoid object instantiation.

Something like,

```
public class WinformHelper
{
    public static ExitProgram(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
     //Your business logic
    }
}
```

Use in winforms,

```
WinformHelper.ExitProgram(sender, e);
```

Comment: Well, that does help me by removing the initialization, but now I am not sure if this is a better solution, or creating a base class for my forms like in the comments to my question. What do you think is better?

Comment: If @JonSkeet, suggesting the same solution, then this is **best solution**

Comment: I'd strongly recommend following .NET naming conventions at the same time, mind you...